# html/php, uploaded files not being stored in $_FILES

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a form where a user submits the description of an object (including an image) and there is JavaScript that adds an additional set of inputs for +1 object description. When the form is submitted the file information is not stored in $_FILES.

The form tag is `<form id="order_form" name="order_form" method="post" action="#">`

The file type input is `<input type="file" name="order_image[]" />`.

`print_r($_FILES);` returns

`array()`

Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be happening. I will gladly include any other information that might be pertinent to this question.

Comment: what's your <form> code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you set the correct encoding type in your form tag?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=...>
```

Comment: I don't have any `enctype` type set so  I will have to do that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

be sure you include enctype