# $_FILES contents blank

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

I have a question about the $_FILES global variable in php. When I do a print_r on my files array I get a blank array() 1 displayed (but I have uploaded one file with post from a form on another page). The post variable for upload (upload being the input type = file name) is set to the filename but nothing in Files is set and if I try and call $_FILES['upload']['name'] nothing shows up. What could be causing this? When I submit my form I have a bunch of different fields (text boxes, select boxes, checkboxes, etc.) but that shouldn't effect my file upload right?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your form `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?  Have you exceeded `upload_max_size`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html/php, uploaded files not being stored in $_FILES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990148/html-php-uploaded-files-not-being-stored-in-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your form tag has the `enctype=multipart/form-data` attribute set:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you all so much I was trying to debug this for hours with absolutely no knowledge of the enctype attribute!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your form has the `enctype` attribute, e.g.:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```